Prevent tap vibration after disabling right click context menu on HTML element?
I have this code, which works for disabling the context menu from appearing after right clicking an element:
function disableRightClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

elem.addEventListener("contextmenu", disableRightClick);

This works on desktop, but on mobile it causes an unfortunate haptic feedback slight vibration after tapping and holding for a few hundred milliseconds on mobile.
How can I get rid of this slight vibration? I tried adding user-select: none to the element, touch-action: none, etc. but nothing seems to work.
If I remove the disableRightClick callback, the phone no longer vibrates when tapping. I suppose I could detect if it was a desktop device somehow (screen width?), and only add the disableRightClick conditionally (since mobile obviously doesn't need it, and it just causes this annoying vibration), but that seems like a bad solution

Which browsers on which mobile operating systems are you testing?

@CommonsWare The latest Chrome version on the latest Android phone

I noticed that the contextmenu event is not supported in Safari on iOS. In general it is not a good idea to hinder usability of the browser.

Isn't iOS mobile? I only need to support disabling it on desktop anyway

Yes, Apple phones and tables. OK, so your question is how to detect whether the user is using a mobile or a desktop? Or are you asking if there's another alternative?

My question is how to disable right click on desktop devices without causing tap vibrations on mobile. Once e.preventDefault() is called in the contextmenu callback, mobile devices start vibrating when you press the element

You can cancel existing vibrations, but I'm not sure that will work, nor is it supported by every browser. You can detect support with const canVibrate = window.navigator.vibrate;. Which would maybe be an excellent addition to the const isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in window; in your answer?

This solution "works", but I'd prefer a solution that didn't require feature detection:
const isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in window;

function maybeDisableRightClick(e) {
  if (!isTouchDevice) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

elem.addEventListener("contextmenu", maybeDisableRightClick);

